# How can I make Shopify refresh the page when an item is added to cart?

Tags: e-commerce, shopify

I have a Shopify site with a slide out cart that shows on every page.

To do this I have copied the content from the cart page and added it to a slide toggle in the main template.

Because of this, when an item is added to the cart, it does not show in the slide out cart.

Is there a way to refresh the page whenever a product is added to the cart, so that it appears in the cart?

Comment: why don't you use the ajax cart from shopify.

Comment: Thanks - but I can't find any documentation on setting this up if you can help me find that. Is it included in any of the default themes?

Comment: @miglio please see above, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i have used this [Shopify's Ajax API](https://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-use-ajax-api) for get,insert,update,delete the cart

```
// Example to add product with properties
addItem=function(product,callback) {
  var params = {quantity:product.qty,id:product.id};
  if(product.properties != false){
      params.properties = product.properties;
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/add.js',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: params,
    success: function(){
        if(typeof callback === 'function'){
            callback();
        }
    },
    error: function(){}
  });
} 
//
var product = {qty:1,id:541926339,properties:{size:2}}
addItem(product,function(){ alert('success');});
```

Comment: this template show the cart using  the ajaxcart [https://furniture-supply.myshopify.com](https://furniture-supply.myshopify.com)

Comment: @migilo - thanks! do you have an example of the html for the cart to retrieve this?